# Yii2 - How to exclude methods from authenticator behaviors

Tags: php, web-services, api, yii, yii2

i am building an API with Yii2 framework, i need to tell yii some actions act as public action.
i added except in my controller's behaviors function but its not works

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['NotifyOrder'],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}

public function actionNotifyOrder() {
    echo 1;
}
```

i am always getting following error when i call my /notify-order url

```
<response><name>Unauthorized</name><message>Your request was made with invalid credentials.</message><code>0</code><status>401</status><type>yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException</type></response>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-actionfilter.html#$only-detail) you need to tell it the **action IDs** (the dash-separated format used in urls)

you should have

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    'except' => ['notify-order', 'another-action', 'and-so-on'],
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but its give XML Parsing Error: syntax error

Comment: @AZinkeyare you returning a correctly formatted xml reply?

Comment: in that function i want to do some custom code which is not return a XML output but yii takes it as XML response